# If proptype of element what is the default?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

if I try to set a proptype as `PropTypes.element`, not required, what is the proper default?

```
static propTypes = {
    expandable: PropTypes.bool,
    popover: PropTypes.element,
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    expandable: false,
    popover: () => {},
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: is it `React.createElement('div')`. Just guessing here!

Comment: Yes, that worked. I had tried `React.createElement()`, forgot it needed an actual element tag. Make that an answer and I'll approve

Comment: Why would you have an extra element? If it's optional, you need no default. Simply have conditional render `{this.props.popover || null}` -same applies for your boolean. `if (this.props.expandable){}` -> `<Component expandable />` -> truthy

Comment: Well, when you use Airbnb's linting, if you define a proptype as not required, it forces you to have a default. Makes sense in a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value could be:

```
React.createElement('div')
```

Comment: Careful here, this solution will "pollute" the dom with an unwanted element, which can cause layout problem (in a css grid for instance), spacing problem (when using selectors that count elements) or simply add unwanted space where there should not be any.

Answer (score 8):

The proper default, or non existing component, in React is `null`. You can use it in `render()` like that:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>{this.props.popover ? this.props.popover : null}</div>
    );
}
```

or simply define it in staticProps:

```
static defaultProps = {
    expandable: false,
    popover: null,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `undefined`should work.

```
static defaultProps = {
  expandable: false,
  popover: undefined,
}
```