# What is the correct value for a `defaultProp` that corresponds to a `PropTypes.element`?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

I have a component that I wish to accept another component as a prop, and render that.  I wish for that passed component to be optional, and render nothing in that case.

The following code works perfectly:

```js
const Component = ({ Inner }) => (
  <div style={{ borderStyle: "solid" }}>
    <Inner />
  </div>
);

Component.propTypes = {
  Inner: PropTypes.element
};

Component.defaultProps = {
  Inner: () => null
};
```

However, on the first load of the page, `prop-types` complains:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `Inner` of type `function` supplied to `Component`, expected a single ReactElement.

My current solution is to redefine the `propType` as `PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.element, PropTypes.func])`, but this seems entirely incorrect.

What should my `propType` or `defaultProp` actually be?

[SSCCE in a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/inspiring-tdd-opbqj).

This question is similar to [If proptype of element what is the default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329679/if-proptype-of-element-what-is-the-default), but that has accepted an answer that doesn't work, and even if it did, it's not a great deal of help to me, as I'm using react native for real.  I've not framed the question in a manner pertaining to react native, as like I said, my example *works*, it's just `prop-types` being a big meanie.

Comment: Did you try any of the non-accepted answers? An answer is accepted only because it helped the OP, not because it's the only "correct" answer.

Comment: Yes,  The second suggests to render `null` manually, which is the opposite of what I want.  The third doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the type of elementType will resolve your problem.

```
Component.propTypes = {
  Inner: PropTypes.elementType
};
```

Since your prop is a react component thus we use elementType. If you ever open the source code for the prop-types you will find this there.

[image]

Hope so this is helpful to you.

Comment: Man I wish this was documented.  :/  https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes